# Javascript code not working on Laravel Header file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel project and there is a login modal inside the project which logs the user in but if the user enters invalid data then I want the modal to pop up automatically with the error message.
I am using this script code but it is not working.No J code is working on the header.blade.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (count($errors) > 0)
$('#login-modal').modal('show');
@endif
</script>
```

My header.blade.php File is:

```
    <header id="header" class="header-scroll top-header headrom">
    <!-- .navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
        <div class="container tog">
            <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbarCollapse">&#9776;</button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/')}}"> <img class="img-rounded" src="images/logo.png" alt=""> </a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="location-top">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="nav-float">
                    <a style="color: white;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;FEEL LIKE EATING &nbsp;
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html"><img src="images/bbq.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;BB.Q</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html"><img src="images/beef.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Beef Roast</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html"><img src="images/carrot.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Carrot Juice</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html"><img src="images/cheese-burger.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cheese Burger</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html"><img src="images/turkey.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Chicken Roast</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html"><img src="images/noodles.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Chinese Soup</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html"><img src="images/frappe.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cold Coffee</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="nav-float-2"> <a style="color: white;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; CHOOSE LOCATION &nbsp;</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html">Location 1</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html">Location 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html">Location 3</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html">Location 4</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html">Location 5</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html">Location 6</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="food_results.html">Location 7</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="map_results.html">Location 8</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="nav-float-2"> <a style="color: white;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle btn btn-danger warning-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Menu &nbsp;</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/chefs')}}"><img src="images/chef.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Chefs</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="images/about-us.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;About Us</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="images/letter.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Us</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="images/question.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;FAQ's</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="mainNavbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-lg-right">
                    @guest
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>LOGIN / REGISTER</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a style="color: white;" class="nav-link btn btn-danger" href="#">REGISTER AS A CHEF</a> </li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a style="border-radius: 20px;" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-danger" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="drop-outside"><a href="/customer/home">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        View Profile
                                    </a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="drop-outside">
                                    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endguest

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.navbar -->
</header>
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <img class="img-circle center-block" id="img_logo" src="images/circle-logo.png">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
            <div id="div-forms">

                <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                <form id="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-login-msg">
                            <div id="icon-login-msg" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-login-msg">Login to Continue..</span>

                        </div>
                        <br>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input id="login_username" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

                        <input id="login_password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <script>
                                $(window).on('load',function(){
                                    $('#login-modal').modal('show');
                                });
                            </script>
                            <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                        @endif
                        @if ($errors->has('password')){
                        <script>
                            $(window).on('load',function(){
                                $('#login-modal').modal('show');
                            });
                        </script>
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block login-btn">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div><p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 15px;">OR</p></div>
                        <div class="social_login">
                            <div class="">
                                <a href="#" class="social_box fb">
                                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
                                    <span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>

                                </a>

                                <a href="#" class="social_box google">
                                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
                                    <span class="icon_title">Connect with Google</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                            <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End # Login Form -->

                <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-lost-msg">
                            <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-lost-msg">Enter your email</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block">Send</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                            <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->

                <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                <form id="register-form" style="display:none;" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-register-msg">
                            <div id="icon-register-msg" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <input id="email" class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                        <input id="password" class="form-control" name="password"type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <input id="password-confirm"  class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Log In</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End | Register Form -->

            </div>
            <!-- End # DIV Form -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END # MODAL LOGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    $('#login-modal').modal('show');
    alert("Hello");
    @endif
</script>
```

I am new to travel and I don't know what's wrong.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any errors in the dev console?

Comment: When are you adding jQuery to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JavaScript and jQuery is Correct and that you have Bootstrap JS installed.

You can do the follow which will run the script if any errors are detected

```
<script>
@if ($errors->any())
$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
@endif
</script>
```